# How to get output from JNI (native) method implemented in C back to Java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a thirdparty native subroutine in C that wants to output it's results to a file descriptor.  I can choose the file descriptor (including standard output, stdout, if I want) by passing it to the C subroutine, but I cannot have it output to anything other than a file descriptor.  I have created my own C code to act as an interface between Java and this C subroutine.

How can I get the output of the C subroutine back to Java directly... that is, without writing it to a file then reading it back in?

The output is usually in the neighborhood of 20-30k and is plain human readable text, so it isn't terribly large and is meaningful to my users.  I'd like to display the output to the user in a Java console like window as it is being output.  Is this possible?  And how?

I see Java has a FileDescriptor object... is this part of the solution?  I do not want to plug my C fd into the FileDescriptor object (using a private field of FileDescriptor) as described here: http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/jni-filedesc.html

I'd like to do this using Java best practices and idioms.

Comment: if the data is a plain byte/char array, you can simply use jbyteArray/jcharArray as return type for the JNI function

Comment: You may be able to print to stdout if you want the text to appear in the java console/shell that the application was run from. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: Paul, the native code is writing to a file descriptor... so I do not have an array of characters or bytes to return.  But based on your comment, I could possibly create a file descriptor that stores the output in an array of bytes in my C code and return that...

Comment: SamTebbs33, I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't work on Windows for some reason, but it does work in Mac OS X.  It may not work on Windows due to some quirk of the compilers I'm using... I'm using Intel and Microsoft compilers on Windows... and there's some Fortran code in there, too, that I haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix-like system, consider creating a *named pipe* and then opening it in both native and Java code as though it were a normal file.

This is similar to using a temporary file, except that the data goes directly from the writer to the reader without being stored on disk.

The downside is that you will still have to manage a temporary named pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I need the solution to work on Windows, too.